# How to remove the whole simulation with the same conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, simulation

I have a dataset:

```
Simulation  Time    BTC
   1          1     0
   1          2     0
   1          3     0
   2          1    23
   2          2    45
   2          3    55
```

I want R to delete all simulation if `Time = 1` and `BTC = 0`.

The expected output will be:

```
Simulation  Time    BTC 
   2          1      23
   2          2      45
   2          3      55
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` `groupby` with `any`

```
df%>%group_by(Simulation)%>%
      mutate(n=any(Time==1&BTC==0))%>%
      filter(!n)%>%
      select(-n)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Simulation [1]
  Simulation  Time   BTC
       <int> <int> <int>
1          2     1    23
2          2     2    45
3          2     3    55
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution using `ave`

```
df[!with(df, ave(Time == 1 & BTC == 0, Simulation, FUN = any)), ]

#  Simulation Time BTC
#4          2    1  23
#5          2    2  45
#6          2    3  55
```

which can be translated to `dplyr` (same as @Wen-Ben)

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 group_by(Simulation) %>%
 filter(!any(Time == 1 & BTC == 0))
```

and for completeness `data.table` translation

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[!any(Time == 1 & BTC == 0)], by = Simulation]
```

---

Another Base R option without any grouping

```
df[!with(df, Simulation %in% Simulation[Time == 1 & BTC == 0]),]
```